# What are basis function and how do we use them to find matrix representation of a group?

Tags: representation-theory, physics, characters

In a lecture note(written for **physics** graduate student) i found the following exercise:

Recall that $V=R^2$ is a $2$ dimensional representation of $D_3$(symmetries of triangle),hence $V \otimes V$ is also a representation of $D_3$,in particular consider the completely symmetric tensor product of $k$ copies of $V$.Each vector in $V$ is labeled by the coordinates $(x_1,x_2)$ of position vectors.

> For $k=1$ we can take the the basis functions to be $x_1,x_2$ then for $k=2$ one can take the three basis functions $\phi_1=x_1^2,\phi_2=x_2^2,\phi_3= \sqrt2 x_1x_2$.Use $\phi_i$ to find $3$ dimensional matrix representation of $D_3$.

In my Representation theory course (for pure maths students)if i recall correctly i never heard about basis functions so i am wondering what are these basis functions and how do we use them to construct a matrix representation?

Answer (score 3):

Physicists talk about math in a slightly different way than mathematicians, so I sympathize with your confusion.  I think what's going on here is that the original representation $V$ is a vector space of functions.  You're saying $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, but an isomorphic version would be the *dual* of $\mathbb{R}^2$, or linear functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  It's spanned by the coordinate functions $x_1$ and $x_2$.  The symmetric tensor powers of $V^*$ are polynomials in two variables.

So the author is using *basis functions* to mashup these structures of $S^kV^*$.  The use of *basis* comes from its nature as a vector space; the use of *function* because they are in in fact functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I see..it makes sense now thank you :-)